# Объясните ошибку при использовании button в fragment android studio

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-notification, android-button

У меня есть фрагмент на котором я хочу разместить кнопку, которая будет добавлять новый `notification` при нажатии на нее, может я не правильно инициализировал `button` или что-то не дописал, так как при нажатии на кнопку у меня слетает приложение с ошибкой:

```
07-18 10:32:21.852 7946-7946/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.developer_4.testproject, PID: 7946
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.testproject/com.example.developer_4.testproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.developer_4.testproject.First.onViewCreated(First.java:29)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2623)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2410)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2365)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2272)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3271)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3227)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:610)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6696)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

при таком коде самого фрагмента:

```
public class First extends Fragment {
Button btnShopsInMap;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btnShopsInMap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnShopsInMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Магазинов нет для отображения", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

я перечитал данную ошибку, и если я правильно понял то, у меня не находит метод `onClick` хотя он есть и должен работать. Если кто знает в чем проблема то буду очень благодарен если покажите где именно и что я не правильно написал так как я раньше с фрагментами не работал.

Comment: пишите инициализацию в onViewCreated

Comment: ничего если честно не понял, в какой элемент? button?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо теперь вроде инициализировалось))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте по этому примеру сделать

```
public class SearchShopsFragment extends Fragment{
    Button btnShopsInMap;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shops, container, false);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        btnShopsInMap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnShopsInMap);
        btnShopsInMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Магазинов нет для отображения", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: ваш способ походу не работает, я вставил ваш код и подогнал его под себя но как-то приложение сразу слетело.

Comment: Обновите ваш текущий код и протестирую его у себя

Comment: обновил код, и перезалил еще раз ошибку, может я где-то опять ошибся?))

Comment: судя по ошибке, у вас не видна кнопка. Вы уверены, что у нее в разметке xml id = button2?

Comment: И добавьте код XML (layout) фрагмента

Comment: спасибо, я идиот))) нужно было это проверить, у меня просто есть и button2 и button3, так вот это button3))